# Как получить URL пользователя vk, facebook куда он расшарил ссылку?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день,
На сайте имеются кнопки поделиться для VK и facebook. Если пользователь решает поделиться, то как узнать URL его странички куда он добавил информацию о нашем сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Наличие подобной возможности являлось бы серьёзной уязвимостью, позволяющей сайту, на котором размещена ссылка на сторонний ресурс, иметь доступ к данным пользователя, авторизованном на этом ресурсе.